# Integrating IASKAppSettingsViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, settings.bundle

I am not able to integrate IASKAppSettingsViewController into my tab bar.

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to happen storyboard should look like:

[UITabBarController]-->[UINavController]-->*RootControllerSegue*-->[UITableViewController]

set class for [UITableViewController] as "IASKAppSettingsViewController"

set [UITableView] style as "Grouped"